# Reverse legend AND place legend outside of stacked bar chart - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have made a stacked bar chart with 13 categories. Currently, the order of the legend is the opposite to what I need.
I know that there is simple code to reverse the legend (which I have included in my code below). However, when i used the plt.legend code to place the legend outside of the graph, it overrides the reverse legend.

Is there any code I could add into the plt.legend() to reverse the legend order?

Thanks.
Code detailed below.

```
df.plot.bar(x='Quarters', stacked=True, title='Top topics quarterly - proportion', color=['red', 'darkorange', 'gold', 'yellowgreen', 'darkgreen', 'turquoise', 'deepskyblue', 'navy', 'blueviolet', 'magenta', 'pink', 'grey', 'black'], legend='reverse')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.xlabel('Quarter', labelpad=10)
plt.ylabel('Proportion of topic', labelpad=10)
```

Edit to add screenshot of df: [image: dataframe used to create stacked bar chart]

[image: Graph that I want to reverse the legend for]

Comment: Please can you provide an input dataframe?

Comment: @Corralien I have added a screenshot of the df and the graph. Thanks

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle yourself the legend with `Axes` instance returned by `plot.bar`:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(x='Quarters', stacked=True, title='Top topics quarterly - proportion', color=['red', 'darkorange', 'gold', 'yellowgreen', 'darkgreen', 'turquoise', 'deepskyblue', 'navy', 'blueviolet', 'magenta', 'pink', 'grey', 'black'])
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], title='Topics', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.xlabel('Quarter', labelpad=10)
plt.ylabel('Proportion of topic', labelpad=10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]